# MillennialMedia on Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, millennial-media

I'm trying to use MillennialMedia  ad on xamarin android project however, i cannot adView.setId(MMSDK.getDefaultAdId()); it seems setId does not exits also I get error on mmsdk. I'm pretty sure that the binding the 100% correct though. Any idea!?

Comment: Did you create this binding yourself?  Then you should be able to look at the binding code to see how setId is mapped.  Generally set methods are replaced with C# style properties - so setValue/getValue would become just Value

Comment: I'm using the binding on here, https://github.com/Hitcents/monodroid-bindings/tree/master/MillennialMedia I know the SetValue/getValue would become just Value –  but it seems the Id is just read only. has anyone implemented it before?